# Java Event Listener return value

Tags: java

I am using Java8. I have an Listener that calls `onSuccess` when completed with a `customToken`.

```
@Override
public String getCustomToken(Person person) {
    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createCustomToken(person.getUid()).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String customToken) {
            // I would like to return the customToken
        }
    });
    return null;
}
```

**Question**

How do I get this method to return the String `customToken`?

Comment: Nope, if I change `onSuccess` return object to `String`, it gets a compile error: `The return type is incompatible with OnSuccessListener<String>.onSuccess(String)`

Comment: Provide final variable to a container object outside the call but inside the method, let the listener write the token into that container, then get it out and return it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work syntactically:

```
final List<String> tokenContainer = new ArrayList<>();   
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createCustomToken(person.getUid()).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(String customToken) {
        tokenContainer.add(customToken);
    }
});
return tokenContainer.get(0);
```

As said; this works syntactically. But if it really works would depend if the overall flow is happening in one thread; or multiple ones.

In other words: when the above code is executed **in sequence**, then that list should contain exactly **one** entry in the end. But if that callback happens on a different thread, then you would need a more complicated solution. A hackish way could be to prepend

```
return tokenContainer.get(0);
```

with

```
while (tokenContainer.isEmpty()) {
  Thread.sleep(50);
}
return tokenContainer.get(0);
```

In other words: have the "outer thing" sit and wait for the callback to happen. But the more sane approach would be to instead use a **field** of the surrounding class.

Edit: if the above is regarded a hack or not; might depend on your context to a certain degree. The only thing that **really** troubles me with your code is the fact that you are creating a **new** listener; which gets added "somewhere" ... to stay there?! What I mean is: shouldn't there be code to **unregister** that listener somewhere?

Comment: I have one thread (from a RESTful Service) invoking this method. It is expecting a response of String `customToken`. So I don't think the above solution fixes my issue.

Comment: I see you solution with the `sleep` above now, thanks.

Comment: The waiting for the `tokenContainer` to populate will work for me.  Thanks for your help

Comment: Haha, I gave you an up vote, but not ticked as the solution...yet. This will work, but can you suggest a more elegant solution?

Comment: See my updates. I think that part of the my solution might be "OK enough", the thing that me concerns after thinking a while: it could be that this solution (with adding an anonymous object to some listener list) creates a memory leak --- who is responsible for de-registering your listeners?

Comment: I will have a look at the Firebase api to see if there's a way to unregister the Listener.  Thank you for your help

Comment: ALways glad when I can help; and when the questioner gives real, immediate feedback.

Comment: You write, "when the above code is executed in sequence, then that list should contain exactly one entry in the end. But if that callback happens on a different thread, then you would need a more complicated solution," which is inaccurate. If the callback were executed on the same thread then the list would contain zero elements. The listener would be registered but it would not be invoked.

A better solution than sleeping the thread is to use a latch (or semaphore), and release the latch when the value is ready to be retrieved.

Answer (score 4):

Your question is intriguing, but the accepted answer unfortunately provides you with wrong means.

The problem with your question is that of API. You are trying to use callbacks in a way they are not designed to be used. A callback, by definition, is supposed to provide a means to do something asynchronously. It is more like a specification of what to do when something happens (in future). Making a synchronous method like `getCustomToken()` return something that is a result of an inherently asynchronous operation like `onSuccess()` implies a fundamental disconnect.

While dealing with callbacks, it is critical to understand the importance of *continuations*: taking actions when certain events of interest happen. Note that these events may not even happen. But you are specifying in the code the actions to take, if and when those events occur. Thus, continuation style is a shift from procedural style.

What adds to the data flow complexity is the syntax of the anonymous inner classes. You tend to think "oh, why can't I just return from here what `onSuccess()` returns? After all, the code is right *here*." But imagine that Java had no inner classes (and as you may know, (anonymous) inner class can easily be replaced by a class that is not an inner class). You'd have needed to do something like:

```
OnSuccessListener listener = new SomeImplementation();
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createCustomToken(listener);
```

Now, the *code that returned data (String) is gone*. You can even visually reason that in this case, there is no way for your method to return a string -- it is simply not there!

So, I encourage you to think of what should happen if and when (in future) `onSuccess()` is called on the `OnSuccessListener` instance that you pass in. In other words, think twice if you really want to provide in **your** API, the `getCustomToken()` method  (that *returns* a token string, given a `Person` instance).

If you absolutely must provide such a method, you

- Should document that the returned token may be `null` (or something more meaningful like `None`) and that your clients must try again if they want a valid value.
- Should provide a listener that updates a thread-safe container of tokens that this method reads.

Googling around, I found the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens). This also seems to suggest *taking an action* on success (in a continuation style):

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createCustomToken(uid)
    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String customToken) {
            // **Send token back to client**
        }
    });
```

The other problem with trying to provide such API is the apparent complexity of the code for something trivial. The data flow has become quite complex and difficult to understand.

If blocking is acceptable to you as a solution, then perhaps you can use the Callable-Future style where you pass a `Callable` and then later do a `get()` on the `Future` that may block. But I am not sure if that is a good design choice here.

Answer (score 1):

The original accepted answer suggests sleeping the thread, which is a bad solution because you can't know how long the thread needs to sleep. A better solution is to use a [semaphore](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) (or similarly, a [latch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html)). After the listener gets the value, it releases a semaphore, which allows your thread to return the value, as shown below.

```
private final AtomicReference<String> tokenReference = new AtomicReference();
private final Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(0);

public String getCustomToken(Person person) {
    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createCustomToken(person.getUid()).addOnSuccessListener(customToken -> {
        this.tokenReference.set(customToken);
        this.sempahore.release();
    });
    this.semaphore.acquire();
    return this.tokenReference.get();
}
```

Notice also that I used an `AtomicReference` because in order for what you asked for to be possible at all the listener must be called on a separate thread than the thread on which `getCustomToken` was called, and we want the value to be synchronized (I'd guess that behind the scenes Firebase is creating a thread, or this call occurs over the network). Since `this.tokenReference` will be overwritten, it is possible to get a newer value when `getCustomToken` is called more than once, which may or may not be acceptable depending on your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Extract a variable into a suitable scope (class attribute or method variable)

```
private String customToken;

@Override
public String getCustomToken(Person person) {
    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createCustomToken(person.getUid()).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String customToken) {
            this.customToken = customToken
        }
    });
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Don't use instance variables here. If you call the method in parallel with different persons you'll very likely lose one of the tokens.

Comment: Thanks, this looks almost what I need. But I have a RESTful Service calling this method that needs the `customToken`. So setting it on the member variable is fine, but how do I respond to the request?